# Couldn't find WSGI module deploying Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi

Trying to deploy my app with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment) tutorial. Have a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'radio.wsgi'` message.

```
2019-08-21T08:08:21.409841+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-08-21T08:08:21.409849+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'radio.wsgi'
2019-08-21T08:08:21.409960+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-21 08:08:21 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-08-21T08:08:21.441211+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-21 08:08:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-08-21T08:08:21.441415+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-08-21 08:08:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

In some other questions people recomends `python manage.py run_gunicorn` but I have `Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'`

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn radio.wsgi --log-file -
```

wsgi.py

```py
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'radio.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In only those files WSGI is mentioned.

requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.4
gunicorn==19.9.0
lxml==4.4.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
pytz==2019.2
sqlparse==0.3.0
whitenoise==4.1.3
```

This is project structure

```
├── radio
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── player
│   ├── radio
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── static
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── Procfile
```

Comment: How about `mv Procfile radio/`?

Comment: If you look at the [tutorial source code](https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial), you'll see that **Procfile**, **runtime.txt** and **requirements.txt** are all at the same level as **manage.py** which is the root of your project repository.

Comment: @WaketZheng, nope. "No web processes running"

Comment: @dirkgroten, how can I restruct project like this? Цhen I initialized the player application it automatically placed here

Comment: What is "when I initialised the player application"? requirements.txt, runtime.txt, README.md... are all files you added manually in the wrong directory. Just move all these files inside your top `radio` directory. Actually, you probably did it wrong when initialising your git repository. `radio` should be the repository not the directory containing `radio`.

Comment: On Heroku, the `Procfile` must be in the project root. You could move the contents of `radio` into the root directory (e.g. so `manage.py` is alongside `Procfile`), or you can [add the `radio` directory to the Python Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459024/113962).

Comment: @WaketZheng moving `Procfile` won't work, because `Procfile` [must be in the project root](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heroku expects `Procfile` to be in the project root. It is easiest to deploy a Django app if `manage.py` is in the project root as well. For example, if your project layout was:

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── player
├── radio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── setup.py
├── static
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── Procfile
```

then you can run:

```
web: gunicorn radio.wsgi
```

In your case, your Django project is in the `radio` directoy. If you don't want to change the project layout, then you need to add `radio` to the python path so that python imports work:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath radio radio.wsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

After login from terminal using `heroku login` by downloading [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line), you can deploy on `heroku` using `git` by following:

```
git init
git add .
heroku create <app_name> --region <region_name>
git commit -am "SOME MESSAGE"
heroku config:set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1
heroku ps:scale web=1    // (optional)
git push heroku master
```

The ideal project structure shuold be like this...

```
   radio
   ├── db.sqlite3
   ├── manage.py
   ├── player
   ├── radio
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── settings.py
   │   ├── urls.py
   │   └── wsgi.py
   ├── setup.py
   ├── static
   ├── README.md
   ├── requirements.txt
   ├── runtime.txt
   └── Procfile
```