# What do I put in the Procfile for Gunicorn with Django?

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, procfile

I have uploaded by git repo to Heroku, but I am having a hard time finding out the gunicorn command to put in the Procfile. This is my repo path to the wsgi.py
[image: Root]
[image: Mid]
[image: WSGI folder]

So what should I put in my Procfile.

> web: gunicorn image_editor.wsgi --log-file -

is my current Procfile but there is a module not found error. Thanks

---

Edit: Error is this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image_editor'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Couldn't find WSGI module deploying Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587490/couldnt-find-wsgi-module-deploying-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

Do `pip install gunicorn` in your local environment and add it to `requirements.txt`

Comment: I have gunicorn installed already, and it is in the Pipfile. It is installed ok, and listed in pip list on the dyno. The module that isn't found is the wsgi.py one.

Comment: web: gunicorn image_editor.wsgi --log-file -

check this path, it seems incorrect relative path

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the project structure, Procfile should be with manage.py