# ModuleNotFoundError when running wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am given this error when running the wsgi.py file. It happens with and without gunicorn.

```
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264850+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264851+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264851+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264851+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264852+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264852+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264853+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup(name)
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264853+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264853+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264861+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264862+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264862+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264862+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264863+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264863+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264864+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264864+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264864+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264865+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264865+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-05-18T12:49:45.264865+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'image_editor'
```

My structure is image_editor_proj>image_editor>wsgi.py

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587490/couldnt-find-wsgi-module-deploying-heroku/57588621#57588621

Comment: Thanks, I'd already found the issue and it was that, I'm not sure how that didn't come up in the search, I looked for hours :)

Comment: This was it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587490/couldnt-find-wsgi-module-deploying-heroku/57588621#57588621. It was the project structure