# Django deployment to Heroku error: python: can't open file '/app/backend.manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory , is this a Procfile error?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a django project to Heroku and I'm getting slapped left and right with errors but hopefully this is the last one.

```
2022-03-07T22:03:09.363036+00:00 heroku[release.9772]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c 'if curl https://heroku-release-output.s3.amazonaws.com/log-stream?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ3LIQ2SWG7V76SVQ%2F20220307%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220307T220304Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=ddb760b1c36e913b7c0cc984428e3b853cdac67755e4cfa6038cef77a37b6a25 --silent --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 >/tmp/log-stream; then
2022-03-07T22:03:10.031451+00:00 heroku[release.9772]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-07T22:03:10.527868+00:00 app[release.9772]: python: can't open file '/app/backend.manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2022-03-07T22:03:10.706087+00:00 heroku[release.9772]: Process exited with status 2
2022-03-07T22:03:10.901301+00:00 heroku[release.9772]: State changed from up to complete
2022-03-07T22:02:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user email@protonmail.com
2022-03-07T22:03:03.734406+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 922870fe by user email@protonmail.com
2022-03-07T22:03:03.734406+00:00 app[api]: Running release v26 commands by user email@protonmail.com
2022-03-07T22:03:05.039171+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c 'if curl $HEROKU_RELEASE_LOG_STREAM --silent --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 >/tmp/log-stream; then
2022-03-07T22:03:05.039171+00:00 app[api]:   chmod u+x /tmp/log-stream
2022-03-07T22:03:05.039171+00:00 app[api]:   /tmp/log-stream /bin/sh -c '"'"'python backend.manage.py makemigrations - - no-input'"'"'
2022-03-07T22:03:05.039171+00:00 app[api]: else
2022-03-07T22:03:05.039171+00:00 app[api]:   python backend.manage.py makemigrations - - no-input
2022-03-07T22:03:05.039171+00:00 app[api]: fi'` by user email@protonmail.com
2022-03-07T22:03:12.919074+00:00 app[api]: Release v26 command failed by user email@protonmail.com
2022-03-07T22:03:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

And when I try to run the program in a virtual environment on my local machine using the command `heroku local`:

```
6:06:35 PM web.1 |  [2022-03-07 18:06:35 -0400] [33412] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
6:06:35 PM web.1 |  [2022-03-07 18:06:35 -0400] [33412] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
6:06:35 PM web.1 |  [2022-03-07 18:06:35 -0400] [33412] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
6:06:36 PM web.1 |  [2022-03-07 18:06:36 -0400] [33412] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

And so on and so on.

I suspect this has to do with my Procfile. And admittedly, I'm not too sure on how to set it up. I currently have in  my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath backend.feh backend.feh.wsgi --log-file - 
release: python backend.manage.py makemigrations - - no-input
```

And my directory structure is like:

```
runtime.txt
requirements.txt
Procfile
backend/
    |-- __init__.py
        api/
        feh/
            |-- __init__.py
                errorlog
                settings.py
                urls.py
                wsgi.py
        static/
        db.sqlite3
        manage.py
scraper.py
```

I'm positive my Procfile is the cause for this issue but I don't know how to go about debugging this. At the very least, the project runs fine on my venv. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the processes in your `Procfile` is specified correctly.

- The web command's `--pythonpath` should just be `backend` and it should receive the dotted path `feh.wsgi` as an argument:

  ```
  web: gunicorn --pythonpath backend feh.wsgi --log-file -
  ```
- The release command refers to a file called `backend.manage.py`:

  ```
  release: python backend.manage.py makemigrations - - no-input
  ```

  That argument should be a path to a file, not a dotted Python module, and `- - no-input` should be the single argument `--no-input`. Try this instead:

  ```
  release: python backend/manage.py makemigrations --no-input
  ```

Comment: Thank you. But... now I'm getting an error where it says it can't find my feh/ folder.

```
text upon text of logs...
2022-03-08T02:24:28.926500+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feh'```

I suppose this might be for another question then. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, figured out my other error:

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457037/heroku-cant-find-my-settings-py-file), My web line in my Procfile should have been:

`web: gunicorn --pythonpath backend feh.wsgi --log-file - `

Since Django isn't at the root of my project, I have specify django project directory.

I knew my Procfile was the source of all my problems, THANK YOU CHRIS!!!

Comment: @Domini, you're right, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer accordingly in case it helps others.